# VBA : Using a value for range

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, range

How would I use a value as a reference for a range?

```
Dim rawr As Integer
rawr = 2
Do While 0 <> Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(1, rawr).Value
```

and it drops there, and everywhere else I use that method of identifying a cell.

> Error 1004, application-defined or object defined error.

Tried several permutations of it, including :

```
Range([1], rawr}
Range(C1, Rrawr)
Range('C1', 'Rrawr')
Range(1, 'rawr')
```

and on and on. I'm a bit at the end of my rope.

Is there a way to tell the. Range function that I am referencing the 'rawr' value?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference single cell, you should use `Cells(row, column)`. In your case: `Cells(1, rawr)`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! Different things are happening, so maybe progress. got a new error earlier in the module once I changed all the ranges to cells. Code below :

Comment: loopaloop = Worksheets(Sheet1).Cells("m5").Value

Comment: Don't change all `Range`!! Only cases, when you want to reference sinlge cell with two integers: one for row and one for column. ONLY this occurences should be `Cells`. If you want to reference cell with a string, like `"m5"`, you should leave `Range`.

Comment: To Clarify, all instances in this module are single cells with two integers. I'm just trying to get one of the two values of the Cells(value1, value2) to be an int value defined dynamically

Comment: Ok. In order to use cells, you mast past to integers: one for row, one for column: `Cells(row, column)`, A column - 1, B column - 2, etc. So, for example, if yo want to reference cell F7, you shuold write `Cells(7, 6)`.

Answer (score 0):

Example Range("a1") ,  "a1" is string. You describe cell's address as string "a1".

"a1" can described as **"a" & 1** or **"a" & "1".**

range("a1") is equeal  cells(1,1) or [a1].

If variable i is integer.

```
for i = 1 to 10
    range("a" & i) = i
next i
```

**"a" & i**  is  string.  The address should be described as string in range object.

Other example.

**range("a1", "b10")**
**range("a1", "b10")**  is same with **range("a1:b10").**
This first address is range's first cell, and this second address is range's last cell.

Other Exampe.

**range("a1", "b10")** is same with **range("a1").resize(10,2).**

resize(rows.count, columns.count).